# Systemd run script after wakeup: "Can't open display"

Tags: systemd

I have a script which does things with screen brightness, works fine that's cool and now I want to make it run after wake up from suspend.

So I tried using systemd, I have a file under `/etc/systemd/system/myscript.service` which is as follows:

```
[Unit]
Description=Run myscript after wakeup
After=suspend.target hibernate.target hybrid-sleep.target suspend-then-hibernate.target


[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/myscript
User=me
#Environment=DISPLAY=:0

[Install]
WantedBy=suspend.target hibernate.target hybrid-sleep.target suspend-then-hibernate.target
```

**Note:** `User` is set because the myscript needs HOME variable.

After I run `sudo systemctl enable myscript` and try suspend/wakeup, myscript is not run and `journalctl -u myscript.service` outputs the following message:

> Jan 25 13:42:53 mymachine myscript[24489]: Can't open display
> Jan 25 13:42:53 mymachine systemd[1]: myscript.service: Succeeded.
> Jan 25 13:42:53 mymachine systemd[1]: Finished Run myscript after wakeup.

If I uncomment the line `#Environment=DISPLAY=:0` in myscript.service the error is "Can't open display :0"

Any help would be great :^)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked on my Arch system.  I tested a script in that location with xbacklight going up and down by 75% a few times after a resume from hibernate or suspend (systemctl hibernate / suspend).

I can only think that you do not have the DISPLAY=:0 in your environment (verify with env) for the user you are running the script as.

Answer (score 1):

I was having a similar problem. Fixed it by adding the following to my systemd service:

```
Environment="DISPLAY=<DISP>"
Environment="XAUTHORITY=/path/to/xauthority"
```

Replace `<DISP>` with the value of your `$DISPLAY` variable, this is usually `:0`.